# A question on $\omega_1$-Cantor Tree

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory

I know the defintion of Cantor Tree. But what is the definition of

$\omega_1$-Cantor Tree? Could someone explain for me or give some links or papers including enough details on $\omega_1$-Cantor Tree?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What is a "Cantor tree"? I never heard the term. Where did you see this $\omega_1$-Cantor tree being referred to?

Comment: see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_tree

Comment: So... what's unclear about the $\omega_1$-Cantor tree? I'd guess this is just the full binary tree of height $\omega_1 + 1$.

Comment: It would be better if you had the definition in the  question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just (as Asaf said) the full binary tree of height $\omega_1$.

So this just the set of all functions $f:\alpha \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, where $\alpha \subseteq \omega_1$ is an ordinal (equivalently some initial segment or the whole set).
The partial order is given by $f \le g$ iff $g|\operatorname{dom}(f) =  f$, so $g$ extends $f$.

The empty function is the root of the tree, the functions defined on $\omega_1$ itself the full "branches".